# Ubuntu 16 timeout errors

Tags: git, ubuntu, timeout

If im trying to update my ubuntu

> sudo apt-get update

At the end I'm getting errors:

> Err http://neurodebian.g-node.org data InRelease
>
> Err http://neurodebian.g-node.org yakkety InRelease
>
> Err http://neurodebian.g-node.org data Release.gpg   Unable to connect
>   to neurodebian.g-node.org:http: Err http://neurodebian.g-node.org
>   yakkety Release.gpg   Unable to connect to
>   neurodebian.g-node.org:http: Fetched 3,653 kB in 2min 0s (30.4 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done W: Failed to fetch
>   http://neurodebian.g-node.org/dists/data/InRelease
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://neurodebian.g-node.org/dists/yakkety/InRelease
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://neurodebian.g-node.org/dists/data/Release.gpg  Unable to
>   connect to neurodebian.g-node.org:http:
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://neurodebian.g-node.org/dists/yakkety/Release.gpg  Unable to
>   connect to neurodebian.g-node.org:http:
>
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Also when I'm trying to clone git:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

I'm getting:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

And If I'm trying to use wayback machine downloader I'm getting errors:

> Getting snapshot pages/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in
>   `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`open'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in`timeout'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in`connect'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in`start'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in`buffer_open'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in`catch'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in`open_uri'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in`open'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader/archive_api.rb:8:in
>   `get_raw_list_from_api'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:88:in`
>   get_all_snapshots_to_consider'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:105:in
>   `get_file_list_curated'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:168:in`
>   get_file_list_by_timestamp'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:309:in
>   `file_list_by_timestamp'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/lib/wayback_machine_downloader.rb:192:in`
>   download_files'
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/wayback_machine_downloader-2.2.1/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:72:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:23:in`load'
>           from /usr/local/bin/wayback_machine_downloader:23:in `'

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are "offline" one way (unplugged cable) or another (your gateway is not letting you out).  See e.g. https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/troubleshooting-network-connectivity-with-ping-and-traceroute to troubleshoot your network connection using ping, traceroute etc commands